# find and replace with \| to two spaces

Tags: sed

How to replace `\|` to (two empty spaces) in a file

I was trying below line but it is not working

```
sed -i "s/\\\|/  /" c:\\test.txt
```

Comment: Why have you put `|` before the filename?

Comment: Additionally, you'd need to escape the `\`.

Comment: After removing | before filename also there is no change in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/\\|/  /" c:\test.txt
```

1 escape for `\` not for `|` and no double `\\` for file name

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i "s/\\|/  /" file
```

The backslash needs to be escaped `\\` however the pipe does not `|`. If you escape the pipe it becomes a metacharacter `\|` which is the [*alternative*](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) operator.